# Ubuntu Boots Directly into Guest Session

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

I'm running 17.10 Artful on an Asus Transformer with Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4 64-bit processor. Dual boot with Windows 10.  Default boot is to Ubuntu.  Just started booting directly into Guest session with no login.  How do I get to boot to a login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Check lightdm configuration file (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf) for below lines,

allow-guest=true/false 
autologin-guest = true/false

Comment: In 17.04, edit this file, /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-no-guest.conf

Comment: Thanks but there is no such file in 17.10.  There is a ..."/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf" but no entry for"allow-guest...